# Is it possible to expire a cookie with Selenium?

Tags: selenium

I would like to test a scenario where the user session expires, without introducing a change in the web site. Is it possible to tweak the cookie using Selenium to force its expiration without waiting for standard timeout?

Comment: Which technologies? Java? Ruby? What? I have solution in java and using javascript.

Comment: ASP.NET, but I imagine the solution would be similar regardless of framework.

Comment: try with javascript solution, actually I don't know asp.net :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1 : Using Java Script**

```
String jScript_ = "" +
"Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString()))\n" +
"Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)\n" +
"Response.Cache.SetNoStore()\n" +
"Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache")";

selenium.getEval(jScript_);
```

**Solution 2** : You can create one bat file which clear your browser or application cache before test start. after creating bat file just call in your code before test start.

**Solution 3: Using Java**

```
protected void deleteCookie(String cookieName) {
 String cookieDomain = CTPropertiesManager.getProperty("site.properties", "site.cookie.domain");
 try {
  //get all cookies
  Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
  Cookie ctCookie=null;
  if (cookies !=null) {
   for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
    ctCookie=cookies[i];
    if (ctCookie.getName().trim().equals(cookieName)) {
     if ( cookieDomain != null ) {
      ctCookie.setDomain(cookieDomain);
     }

     ctCookie.setPath("/ct");
     ctCookie.setMaxAge(0);
     response.addCookie(ctCookie);
    }
   }
  }
 } catch(Exception e){
  CTLogManager.log(e);
 }
}
```

**Solution 4:**
I create one method and placed below code

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

sel.refresh();

driver.navigate().to(YOUR FILE PATH);

Comment: solution 1 prevents page from being cached and has nothing to do with expiration of the authentication cookie; solution 2 just clears all cookies, which, again, does not help in testing the scenario where user session expired; solution 3, I suspect, would work, but is also the solution I am trying to avoid -- I want to be able to test this scenario without altering server code.

Comment: When I placed solution 4, its works for me. - I understand you want a delete the browser cache without having restart the browser