# Change time webdriver selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to make a jump in time on my web application running in selenium web driver.

**Context**
Let's say I have a single page application (actually angular app) that automatically log out if the user is inactive for 8 minutes. I would like to test this. I am using selenium for functional testing and it is the only way to test my front end right now. Using chrome driver to start the application in chrome browser. I don't want to write a test and wait 8 minutes to make sure the user is logged out correctly.

Is there a way I could achieve this using selenium without having to wait the entire 8 minutes?

Comment: In my experience, there is some JS that triggers this timeout. If you find that, you can edit the expiration time and call it again to trigger the timeout earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can do that. Probably you can try to manipulate the cookie or localStorage by clearing it via javascript or look for some 3rd party program to manipulate the time on the machine.

Also check this question & answers -> [Is it possible to expire a cookie with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541163/is-it-possible-to-expire-a-cookie-with-selenium)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I manage to test the behaviour by setting the storage in my test then I refresh the page to make the app look in storage for timeleft. This way I can manipulate the time to make it just about to expire. :)